# how to reverse string only do not numbers and special characters in a line

Tags: unix, sed

I want reverse a string of characters from a file using `sed`. However, I want the expression do not reverse the numbers and special characters.

For example, consider the following input:

```
112358 is a fibonacci sequence...
a test line
124816 1392781
final line...
```

My expected output is :

```
112358 si a iccanobif ecneuqes...
a tset enil
124816 1392781
lanif enil...
```

I have tried it in several ways, but i could not find the exact expression for that.
I have tried the following expression but it has reversed the entire string:

```
sed '/\n/!G;s/\([.]\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
```

Comment: What should happen if the input contains a string which contains digits, eg `this5string`?

Comment: Is this a homework, because someone else asked the same question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232846/how-to-reverse-the-lower-case-characters-in-word-using-only-sed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sed script will do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed

# Put a \n in front of the line and goto begin.
s/^/\n/
bbegin

# Marker for the loop.
:begin

# If after \n is a lower case sequence, copy its last char before \n and loop.
s/\n\([a-z]*\)\([a-z]\)/\2\n\1/
tbegin

# If after \n is not a lower case sequence, copy it before \n and loop.
s/\n\([^a-z]*[^a-z]\)/\1\n/
tbegin

# Here, no more chars after \n, simply remove it before printing the new line.
s/\n//
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Perl` for this. The code is much more readable:

```
perl -pe 's/\b([A-Za-z]+)\b/reverse($1)/ge' file
```

Results:

```
112358 si a iccanobif ecneuqes...
a tset enil
124816 1392781
lanif enil...
```